# How do I reply in-thread to a non-latest email with Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to make a script that sends an email to an address that it is not the latest in a thread discussion.

*Ex.* A thread has emails sent by the following senders (from oldest to newest):
(1) A@gmail.com (2) B@gmail.com (3) C@gmail.com

I want to be able to make an in-thread reply to A@gmail.com but [GmailThread.reply(body, option)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#reply(String,Object)) overrides `replyTo` field (trying to define this field anyway seems to be ineffective).

---

While I can put A@gmail.com in CC, this is far from ideal as C@gmail.com is considered the real recipient.

Sending a new mail through script makes a new thread as the sender, even if the receiver apparently sees one thread.

I am looking to have at least the sender seeing the generated email as one belonging to the original thread.

Comment: You probably want to find the right message within the thread and use [GmailMessage.reply()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#reply(String)) rather than `GmailThread.reply`

Answer (score 0):

As per Dmitry Kostyuk's comment, you have to look for the message in a thread you want to reply to and use [GmailMessage.reply()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#reply(String)) instead of GmailThread.reply().

Unfortunately GmailMessage.reply() still overrides `replyTo` field, which might be an obstacle if you want to send an email based on a message that you have previously sent. The best alternative is [GmailMessage.replyAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replyallbody) which adds both recipient and receivers of the GmailMessage of reference to the email's "To" field. This collaterally adds also you as the receiver, but it can be perceived as a way to have a notification of the email sent.

The so-created email in your own inbox can be set as read or deleted immediately after sending, achieving somewhat ideal result.